Stream console logs from device
I have an iPhone connected to my MacBook and I'm trying to stream the console logs from it via my terminal.
I saw this answer that uses the --device-name option for log collect.  However, log stream has no similar option.
I also tried idevicesyslog but those logging messages are not what I'm looking for.  That is, when I ran idevicesyslog in the terminal simultaneous with the Console GUI, I got different messages.
